# creating a bootstrap script for node projects run by node

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I'm making a script to bootstrap all my projects so that project creation is as simple as run '**node bootstrap.js**' and the script initializes the directory, creates basic project folder structure, installs dependencies (e.g: nodemon, dotenv, jest, etc...) and configures scripts inside *package.json*, for example '**nodemon -r dotenv/config index.js**' for starting nodemon with dotenv preload. When I start the script, I create the folder structure, then I create sample files in each folder, and last I execute the following part of the script:

```
// Lets add the scripts inside package.json
addScriptsToPackageJson = () => {
    const packageJsonFilename = './package.json';
    let packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(packageJsonFilename, 'utf8'));

    packageJson.scripts['test'] = 'jest --coverage';
    packageJson.scripts['dev'] = 'nodemon -r dotenv/config index.js';
    fs.writeFile(packageJsonFilename, JSON.stringify(packageJson, null, 2), function writeJSON(err) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(packageJson));
        console.log('writing to ' + packageJsonFilename);
    });
}

// Promisify exec command
function execShellCommand(cmd) {
    const exec = require('child_process').exec;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
            if (error) {
                console.warn(error);
            }
            resolve(stdout? stdout : stderr);
        });
    });
}

// Initialize project and download base dependencies
execShellCommand('npm init -y')
    .then(response => execShellCommand('npm install --save-dev nodemon dotenv jest'))
    .then(response => execShellCommand('npm install express'))
    .then(addScriptsToPackageJson())
    .catch(error => {console.log("ALGO SALIO MAL")});
```

but function *addScriptsToPackageJson* throws the following error:

```
internal/fs/utils.js:220
    throw err;
    ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './package.json'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:440:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:342:35)
    at addScriptsToPackageJson (F:\Repositories\node-project-bootstraper\prueba\bootstrap.js:94:37)
    at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Repositories\node-project-bootstraper\prueba\bootstrap.js:109:11)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:955:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:811:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11 {
  errno: -4058,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: './package.json'
}
```

I presume this is because at compile time the file *package.json* does not exist, it just exists after the '**npm init -y**' command has completed execution.

Any ideas on how to solve this? I really want to make a script that makes everything without user intervention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're invoking the function prematurely. Instead of

`.then(addScriptsToPackageJson())`

do

`.then(addScriptsToPackageJson)`

Comment: you are the man! Don't know how that passed me by.... thanks!!